# Memory address and offset

Tags: assembly

I have a noob questions about how memory address stores values.

For example,

```
addr  +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F  +0123456789ABCDEF
0000  50 61 78 20 69 73 20 61 20 72 65 61 6C 6C 79 20   Pax is a really 
0010  63 6F 6F 6C 20 67 75 79 00                        cool guy.
```

Is  0000 an address? 
Is  50 61 78 20 69 73 20 61 20 72 65 61 6C 6C 79 20 the value stored in 0000 address?

Comment: What program produced this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addr  +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F  +0123456789ABCDEF
0000  50 61 78 20 69 73 20 61 20 72 65 61 6C 6C 79 20   Pax is a really 
0010  63 6F 6F 6C 20 67 75 79 00                        cool guy.
```

0000 seems to be an address but might be a relative address (or offset).
This output seems to say that

```
addr            value
0000+0 (0000)   0x50  
0000+1 (0001)   0x61
0000+2(0002)    0x78 
  ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Here `0000` is an address, from the label `addr`. The only value that is stored at `0000` is `50`. Each byte has it's own address:

```
------+--------
 addr |  data
------+--------
 0000 | 50
 0001 | 61
 0002 | 78
 0003 | 20
 0004 | 69
 0005 | 73
 0006 | 20
 0007 | 61
 0008 | 20
 0009 | 72
 000A | 65
 000B | 61
 000C | 6C
 000D | 6C
 000E | 79
 000F | 20
```

if you considered for example `0000` as the base address, you can say `20`, the last value is stored at `F` as `0000 + F = 000F`, base address + offset from that address.

Answer (score 2):

`0000` is likely just an offset from a localized address.  Basically, `BaseAddress + 0000`, `BaseAddress + 0010`, etc.

The values are ASCII, and they match the characters on the right.  You've stored a text message (or string) in that memory.

Each memory address stores one byte (also 8 bits, also 2 hexadecimal ("hex") digits).  `0000` (`0000 +0`) has the hex value `50`, `0001` (`0000 +1`) has the hex value `61`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `0000` can be considered an address. As to what is "stored" at `0000`, specifically the value `50` is stored there, and at `0001` the value of `61` is stored, and on and on.

However, with higher level data structures, such as 16 bit integers, or 32 bit integers, or Strings, or even record structures, the answer to "what is stored at `0000`" gets much muddier.

If a 16 bit binary integer is stored at `0000`, for an Intel architecture, then the value would be `6150`, or 24912 in decimal. This is because the Intel is "little endian", and stored the Most Significant bytes later in the address space. For a "big endian" processor, the value is `5160` or 20832 decimal.

Now, this could be coded in Binary Coded Decimal, in that case the value would be 6150 or 5160 in decimal (depending on endian-ness).

So, you can see, even for something as simple as an integer, there are different ways it can  be stored within memory.

So, at the byte level, the answer is pretty simple. Going beyond that, it depends on how the data being stored is represented at the byte level.